# Magento ajax upload in file type over product custom options

Tags: magento-1.9

I want build ajax upload in product custom options in the file type.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found one quick solution for this.

Please add this below in your input type='file'

```
<input id='filePhoto' type="file" name="<?php echo $_fileName; ?>" class="product-custom-option<?php echo $_option->getIsRequire() ? ' required-entry' : '' ?>" <?php echo $_fileExists ? 'disabled="disabled"' : '' ?> data-price="<?php echo $_option->getPrice($_option->getPriceType() == 'percent'); ?>" onchange="opConfig.reloadPrice()" />


        <div id="uploadertest" onclick="jQuery('#filePhoto').click()">
              <p>click here or drag here your images for preview and set userprofile_picture data</p>
              <img src="" style="max-width: 500px; height: auto; float: left;"/>
        </div>
```

Use this css and javascript, this js and css convert your input like drag and drop.

```
<script>
   /* var myDropzone = new Dropzone("div#dropzonewidget", { 
        url: "<?php echo  Mage::getBaseUrl('js').'dragdropjs/upload.php' ?>"
    });
    */
var imageLoader = document.getElementById('filePhoto');
    imageLoader.addEventListener('change', handleImage, false);

function handleImage(e) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (event) {
        jQuery('#uploadertest img').attr('src',event.target.result);
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);

}

var dropbox;
dropbox = document.getElementById("uploadertest");
dropbox.addEventListener("dragenter", dragenter, false);
dropbox.addEventListener("dragover", dragover, false);
dropbox.addEventListener("drop", drop, false);

function dragenter(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
}

function dragover(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
}

function drop(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
  //you can check e's properties
  //console.log(e);
  var dt = e.dataTransfer;
  var files = dt.files;

  //this code line fires your 'handleImage' function (imageLoader change event)
  imageLoader.files = files;
}

// If you use jQuery, you can use the jQuery plugin Dropzone ships with:

</script>
<style type="text/css">
    #uploadertest {position:relative; overflow:hidden;     width: 818px;
    height: 263px; background:transparent; border:2px dashed #e8e8e8;cursor:pointer;padding:5px;color:#555;font-family:'Segoe UI';font-weight:bold;}

#uploadertest:hover{color:#999;}

#filePhoto{
    display:none;
}
#uploadertest p{
    text-align: center;
}

/*#uploadertest img{
    position:absolute;
    width:312px;
    height:362px;
    top:-1px;
    left:-1px;
    z-index:-1;
    border:none;
    background-color: #eee;
}*/
</style>
```